# How can I define a bean type of 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3' in configuration class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to configure AWS in my Spring boot application, however, `AmazonS3` bean isnt recognised in the configuration. As a result I am getting this error:  
`Consider defining a bean of type`com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3' in your configuration`. 

How can I solve this problem?

**AWSConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;


@Configuration
public class AWSConfiguration {
    @Value("${accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${region}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(AWSCredentials awsCredentials) {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withRegion(region).build();
}}
```

**ExampleService.java**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;


@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonClient;

}
```

Comment: could you show the imports of both clases

Comment: @jstuartmilne i have included the imports

Comment: hm.. are u certain you configuration class is getting picked-up?

Comment: It doesnt seem it's getting picked up

Comment: Could you post the class that you annotated with @SpringBootApplication and add the package to the both files you posted